# need to combine button_to and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to combine the link_to tag and the button_to tag so that the button becomes the link..

I need to combine the following two lines of code:

```
        <%= button_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :type => "submit", :class => "style3", :method => "get" %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %>
```

Comment: It's very easy to make either behave like the other, but it doesn't make sense to combine them. What is the the HTML you are hoping to generate?

Comment: i cant understand what you want mate. can you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the confusing question...  This is what I needed..

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/addbutton.png", alt: "Add"),  new_user_path %>
```

Comment: Since the link_to creates a link but I wanted to use an image in place of that link..

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is kind of old but I was trying to do the same thing in which I wanted to use both rails named routes via use of embedded ruby (i.e. <%= something_path %>) and a `<button>` tag in my html. The only way I figured out how to do this is by adding a twitter-bootstrap button class to link_to. If anyone else knows how to do this without using a twitter-bootstrap button and using a plain ol html button please advice, thanks.

```
<%= link_to "Add", new_user_path, :class => "btn btn-mini" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# like this?
def link_bu(value, path)    
  "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location='#{path}';\" value=\"#{value}\"".html_safe
end
```

Comment: you can add this to a helper and use it from your views